# About iOS10 JavaScript & UIWebview interface

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

This morning, suddenly found that our users are saying app crashes after we had breakpoints found iOS 10 of the iphone, JavaScript & UIWebview interface problem occurs in the injected JSContext object, the proxy method can not be performed, and direct crash to the stack area, cause I can not modify on the line.

Comment: Anyone encountered this problem? If anybody has a solution, please answer me.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The following original comment is not helpful. My use of  window.webkit.messagehandlers in UIWebView is an unsupported hack (to match the API of WKWebView), so no surprise that broke, and the overflow crash when attaching Safari is reportedly not happening to other devs who are on Safari 10 (I haven't updated yet)

-- Original Comment --

Seeing the same bug on iOS 10, filing to Apple now. Problem #1, adding callbacks to window.webkit.messagehandlers: this object now only allows for a single callback function added, it used to allow multiple, i.e. messagehandlers.doOneThing, messagehandlers.doAnother.
Problem #2, seeing crashes: first an EXC_BREAKPOINT on WTF::CrashOnOverflow::overflowed() then a crash

`` * thread #10: tid = 0x81c29d, 0x0dfb3d1d JavaScriptCore`JSC::DFG::SpeculativeJIT::speculate(JSC::DFG::Node*, JSC::DFG::Edge) + 1197, name = 'WebThread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x0dfb3d1d JavaScriptCore`JSC::DFG::SpeculativeJIT::speculate(JSC::DFG::Node*, JSC::DFG::Edge) + 1197 ``

Comment: I‘ve solved the problem. It's caused by redeclare function name.I defined two function with same name but with different numbers of arguments, then caused the crash.